# Kohana catch Database_Exception [ 1146 ]

Tags: database, orm, kohana

Is there any way to catch Database_Exception [ 1146 ] (Table 'table_name' doesn't exist) and create one (CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS), according to table structure listed in model ($_table_columns)?

Any assistance would be appreciated.

**UPDATED 29.07.2015** -----------------------------------------------

I solved the exeption cathing part of my question following way:

1. Create an Database Exeption class overriding parent (APPATH/classes/Database/Exeption.php) with following contents:

class Database_Exception extends Kohana_Database_Exception {

```
/**
 * Creates a new translated exception.
 *
 *     throw new Kohana_Exception('Something went terrible wrong, :user',
 *         array(':user' => $user));
 *
 * @param   string          $message    error message
 * @param   array           $variables  translation variables
 * @param   integer|string  $code       the exception code
 * @param   Exception       $previous   Previous exception
 * @return  void
 */
public function __construct($message = "", array $variables = NULL, $code = 0, Exception $previous = NULL)
{       
    // Search for corresponding handler class
    if(class_exists('Database_Exception_Handler_' . $code))
    {
        // Pass the $variables array to the handler
        $handler_class_name = 'Database_Exception_Handler_' . $code;
        $handler_class_name::instance($variables)->handle();

        // Abort further script execution
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {       
        // Pass the message and integer code to the parent
        parent::__construct($message, $variables, $code, $previous);
    }       
}
```

}

2. Create an Exeption Handler class  (APPATH/classes/Database/Exeption/Handler/1146.php) with following contents:

class Database_Exception_Handler_1146 {

```
/**
 * Class instance.
 * 
 * @static
 * @access  protected
 * @var     object
 */
protected static $_instance;

/**
 * Exeption variables.
 * 
 * @static
 * @access  protected
 * @var     array
 */
protected static $_variables;

/**
 * Creates a singleton Database Exception 
 * Handler instance.
 *
 * @static
 * @access  public
 * 
 * @param   array   $variables
 * @return  object
 */
public static function instance(array $variables = NULL)
{
    if( ! is_object(self::$_instance))
    {
        $handler_class_name = __CLASS__;            
        self::$_variables = $variables;         
        self::$_instance = new $handler_class_name();
    }
    return self::$_instance;
}

public static function handle() 
{
    // Here comes handler code...       
}
```

} // End Database_Exception_Handler_1146

So now we can catch and handle any database table errors. In example - [1146] - Table 'database_name.table_name' doesn't exist.

Now I'm wondering how to create table (// Here comes handler code...), and check table structure, according to model property $_table_columns.

Any idea?

Comment: Kohana does not provide any functionality for automatically creating the database from the ORM model, as far as I know at least. Perhaps it would be a better idea to use some other ORM system, like RedBeanPHP (which integrates with Kohana). If you don't want to use another one, you will have to implement this functionality yourself, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks, Aculeo!  I solved the described problem by automatically creating a DB table if it's not exists in Database_Exception_Handler_1146 class, from the table structure configuration file (config/database/table_name.php).

Next step is handling database table field absence.